# Ordering CONNECT BY siblings

Tags: oracle, query-performance, optimization, hierarchy, oracle-19c

I have an [hierarchical query](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Hierarchical-Queries.html) that uses CONNECT BY:

```
select 
    wonum,
    parent,
    classification,
    classstructureid,
    division,
    worktype,
    status, 
    glaccount, 
    fircode, 
    actstart,
    actfinish,
    siteid,

    connect_by_root wonum as topworkpackage,
    level,
    ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(wonum,' \ '),' \ ') wohierarchy
from 
    workorder
where
    istask = 0
    and woclass in ('WORKORDER', 'ACTIVITY')
    and siteid = 'SERVICES'

connect by prior wonum = parent
start with parent is null

order siblings by classification
```

Here's a sample of some of the relevant columns from the query:

| WONUM | PARENT | CLASSIFICATION | TOPWORKPACKAGE | LEVEL | WOHIERARCHY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WO55016 |  | ROADS | WO55016 | 1 | WO55016 |
| WO55015 | WO55016 | ROADS \ WINTER | WO55016 | 2 | WO55016 \ WO55015 |
| WO43181 | WO55015 | ROADS \ WINTER | WO55016 | 3 | WO55016 \ WO55015 \ WO43181 |
| WO43183 | WO43181 | ROADS \ WINTER \ A | WO55016 | 4 | WO55016 \ WO55015 \ WO43181 \ WO43183 |
| WO37342 | WO43181 | ROADS \ WINTER \ B | WO55016 | 4 | WO55016 \ WO55015 \ WO43181 \ WO37342 |
| WO43182 | WO43181 | ROADS \ WINTER \ C | WO55016 | 4 | WO55016 \ WO55015 \ WO43181 \ WO43182 |

---

### **Performance:**

If I run the query **without ordering** the CONNECT BY siblings, then the cost is low (1027):

```
(Note: I *excluded* this line when I ran query: ORDER SIBLINGS BY CLASSIFICATION)

Plan hash value: 1017899897
 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                         |           | 82500 |    74M|  1027  (46)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  FILTER                                  |           |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   CONNECT BY NO FILTERING WITH START-WITH|           |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL                     | WORKORDER | 22158 |  1947K|   566   (2)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - filter("ISTASK"=0 AND ("WOCLASS"='WORKORDER' OR "WOCLASS"='ACTIVITY') AND 
              "SITEID"='SERVICES')
   2 - access("PARENT"=PRIOR "WONUM")
       filter("PARENT" IS NULL)
```

---

However, if I **order** the CONNECT BY siblings, then the cost is high (16975):

```
(Note: I *included* this line when I ran query: ORDER SIBLINGS BY CLASSIFICATION)

Plan hash value: 1017899897
 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                         |           | 82500 |    74M| 16975   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  FILTER                                  |           |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   CONNECT BY NO FILTERING WITH START-WITH|           |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL                     | WORKORDER | 22158 |  1947K|   566   (2)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - filter("ISTASK"=0 AND ("WOCLASS"='WORKORDER' OR "WOCLASS"='ACTIVITY') AND 
              "SITEID"='SERVICES')
   2 - access("PARENT"=PRIOR "WONUM")
       filter("PARENT" IS NULL)
```

---

### Question:

As a novice, I'm wondering:

Is there is a way to optimize **ordering** the CONNECT BY siblings for better performance?

- I've tried adding indexes to the columns that are involved in the ordering/CONNECT BY. But that doesn't seem to help; the indexes don't get used.

Comment: Cost is an estimate. What is the real performance like?

Comment: @AndrewSayer The performance right now seems to be fine. It takes about 1 second to return 20,000 rows. With that said, I'm trying to learn how to optimize the query so that it will perform well in the future with millions of rows. Is that a good approach? Perhaps I should generate more test data (millions of dummy records)?

Comment: What are you going to do with 20,000 rows at once? The optimisation approach would generally be - only get the rows you really need, and put in a supporting index to allow Oracle to identify the starting point and (possibly a second) to do the connect by.

Comment: @User1973 If it's realistic that you'll need to support millions of rows within the next 6 months then you should test with millions of rows now and look at the **plan** generated for millions of rows to see what can be optimized, not base it off of 20,000 rows as those plans can vary. If you're not expecting to support millions of rows for a few years then there's probably no point in trying to optimize for that now as a lot can change between now and then and you probably have other better things you can focus on. Database performance optimization is an ongoing game, no solution is timeless.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when we add "ORDER BY" to a SELECT, the execution cost increases. We get around this by creating/changing the indexes or the "ORDER BY" clause so that they coincide with each other. But even so, it may not be possible or the execution plan may change with time.

There is another solution, sometimes the application wants to access only a small amount of lines at once, in this case you could do a function that will sort only the part that the application will actually use.